# Две задачи на C++ (точки на плоскости)

Tags: c++

*Задача: Найти три треугольника с вершинами в заданном множестве из n точек на плоскости так, чтобы второй треугольник лежал строго внутри первого, а третий внутри второго.*

Никак не могу сообразить в каком направлении думать. Суть как бы понимаю, можно (преподаватель разрешил) сделать полным перебором, но вот как это сделать я совершенно не представляю.

Вторая задача, тоже не могу понять как решить:

*Четыре прямые заданы своими уравнениями, разбивают плоскость на треугольники. Найти треугольник, которому принадлежит точка А. Если это не выполняется, сообщить.*

Comment: Первую задачу полным перебором сделать можно. 1. Для каждой тройки точек (если они не лежат на одной прямой) смотрим, какие точки из оставшихся лежат внутри данного треугольника.  2. Для каждой тройки внутренних точек действует аналогично. 3. Если найдены 3 не лежащие на одной прямой точки внутри второго треугольника, то вывод найденный результат из 9 точек.

Comment: @Regent сама идея полного перебора понятна, я не могу понять как это сделать программно.

Comment: Вторая задача: для каждых трёх прямых (если среди них нет параллельных друг другу) ищем их точки пересечения друг с другом. После этого для получившегося треугольника проверяет принадлежность ему заданной точки.

Comment: Взять и написать код. Видимо, на С++. Вот и всё. Если есть понимание алгоритма и знание С++, то проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Не задавайте два разных вопроса в одном, лучше разнесите их.

Answer (score 2):

Для решения задачи следует перебирать все варианты (по три точки первого, второго и третьего треугольника), при этом каждую точку (вершину) проверяемого треугольника проверять на вхождение в другой треугольник.

То есть если все вершины вошли, то и весь проверяемый треугольник лежит внутри другого.

Для треугольника существует стандартный алгоритм pointInTriangle - проверяет точки на попадание внутрь треугольника: функция возвращает значение TRUE, если точка р находится внутри треугольника а, b и с, в противном случае возвращаемое значение равно FALSE. Функция classify определяет положение точки p относительно прямой, задаваемой аргументами.

Использованные структуры данных (тот же Point) можно посмотреть тут - http://algolist.ru/maths/geom/datastruct.php

```
bool pointInTriangle (Point p, Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
  return ((p.classify (a, b) != LEFT) &&
        (p.classify(b, c) != LEFT) &&
        (p.classify(c, a) != LEFT));
}

enum {LEFT,  RIGHT,  BEYOND,  BEHIND, BETWEEN, ORIGIN, DESTINATION};
//    СЛЕВА, СПРАВА, ВПЕРЕДИ, ПОЗАДИ, МЕЖДУ, НАЧАЛО, КОНЕЦ

int Point::classify(Point &p0, Point &pl)
{
  Point p2 = *this;
  Point a = p1 - pO;
  Point b = p2 - pO;
  double sa = a. x * b.y - b.x * a.y;
  if (sa > 0.0)
    return LEFT;
  if (sa < 0.0)
    return RIGHT;
  if ((a.x * b.x < 0.0) || (a.y * b.y < 0.0))
    return BEHIND;
  if (a.length() < b.length())
    return BEYOND;
  if (pO == p2)
    return ORIGIN;
  if (p1 == p2)
    return DESTINATION;
  return BETWEEN;
}
```

Вам нужно просто реализовать полный перебор всех вариантов точек по 9 точек, с разбивкой по 3 точки.

Answer (score 0):

Задачу №1 можно разбить на 2 части:

1. Определить лежит ли один треугольник "строго" внутри другого (определение того что значит "внутри", да еще и "строго", оставляю на вашей совести).
2. Проверка всех возможных вариантов при помощи двух проверок (1), до
   тех пор пока не будет найдено решение, или не закончатся варианты.

Для того чтобы не делать совсем уж полным перебором, можно предварительно треугольники разложить в какую-то пространственную структуру, например в BVH-дерево/3D-grid. Тогда достаточно будет проверять только комбинации треугольников внутри нода, а не все со всеми.